# Why does drawImage only accept integers?

Tags: java, swing, graphics2d

I'm quite busy with my new project which involves drawing all kind of geometry on a JPanel using Graphics2D.

I do use double for all my x and y coordinates, cause it is easier with certain calculations, for example dividing numbers, using int can lead to strange results.

But now and again i need to draw an image, this is easy i use g2.drawImage(img, x, y, null). But this function doesn't accept double as parameters so i need to cast my double to int, loosing some of the precision.

All other functions i use of graphics2D accept double coordinates/parameters. I even upgraded to java8, but not luck either.

Is there a reason why drawImage only accepts integers?

Comment: Probably so that the edges of the image are bounded by exact pixels rather than being partially on them.

Comment: Probably, also, because `drawImage` is actually defined in `Graphics`, which used `int`s for it's values.  This would also have been before the support API's for `Graphics2D`, including the `Shape`s API.  `Graphics2D` does provide a `drawImage` method which takes a `AffineTransform`, which provides support for `double`'s via it's translation properties. While a interesting question, any answer will only be speculative, unless a member of the `Graphics`/`Graphics2D` group drop by

Comment: You two make two good cases, what @AndyDavies notes does make sense. MadProgrammer i did not know of the existing of the drawImage method with the AffineTransform parameter, i will sure give it a try and see how it works out and if it may cause problems. Thanks for the insights!